# How can I have more than 5 Lambdas consume the same Kinesis stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I would like to have one Kinesis stream with lots of Lambda consumers (different Lambda functions, not just many instances of the same one).

Kinesis has a limit of 5 read transaction per second ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html)). Lambda functions will poll a shard every second.

Does this mean that I should expect my reads to get throttled when I add a sixth Lambda consumer to a stream?

I understand that more than 5 consumers on one stream are doable with the new [Enhanced Fanout feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/introduction-to-enhanced-consumers.html), but I can't find any mention of Lambda functions with regard to this new feature. They only talk about KCL2.

Instead I have found a few older articles of people describing their own fan out implementations to avoid lagging Lambda consumers, e.g., [this one](https://read.acloud.guru/aws-lambda-3-pro-tips-for-working-with-kinesis-streams-8f6182a03113?gi=16d0717686f9). I wonder whether this is still needed or Lambda consumers can take advantage of the new enhanced fanout too.

Comment: Can you have one Lambda Parent (consuming), invoke many lambda children by the parent passing the stream data to the children?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
/* in the parent lambda */

var consumers = [
  {
    id: "consumer",
    eventData: someData // stream data inserted here
  }
]

var params = {
  ClientContext: "MyApp", 
  FunctionName: "MyFunction", 
  InvocationType: "Event", 
  LogType: "Tail", 
  Payload:  null,        // <Binary String> 
  Qualifier: "1"
 };

let invoke = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else     resolve(data);
    });
  })
}

invokeArr = []
consumers.map((consumer) => {
  params.Payload = consumer.eventData
  invokeArr.push(invoke)
})

Promise.all(invokeArr).then((data) => console.log('were done'))
```